# AngularJS clearing up form and ensure validation error after submisison

Tags: angularjs

I am facing and odd situation. I have angularJS form and i have successfully implemented it so that it is clear up after submission and so that my validation error not show, it works nice but after submission, it show a red boarder which is error sign that i dont want.

here you go for my form:

```
<form name='addContactForm'>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userid">USER ID :</label><br>
        <input ng-model="formModel.userid" class="form-control" name="userid" restrict-input="{type: 'digitsOnly'}" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="addContactForm.userid.$dirty && addContactForm.userid.$invalid">
          <span ng-show="addContactForm.userid.$error.required"> User is required.</span>
          <span ng-show="addContactForm.userid.$error.number">Invalid userID</span>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">NAME :</label><br>
        <input ng-model="formModel.name" class="form-control" name="name" required/>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="addContactForm.name.$dirty && addContactForm.name.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="addContactForm.name.$error.required"> Name is required.</span>
            <span ng-show="addContactForm.name.$error.lettersOnly">Invalid Name</span>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email :</label> <br>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="formModel.email" ng-pattern="/[\w\d\.\_]+\@[\w\d]+\.[\w]{3}/" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="addContactForm.email.$dirty && addContactForm.email.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="addContactForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
            <span ng-show="addContactForm.email.$error.pattern">Invalid email address.</span>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone :</label> <br>
        <input ng-model="formModel.phone" class="form-control" name="phone" restrict-input="{type: 'digitsOnly'}" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="addContactForm.phone.$dirty && addContactForm.phone.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="addContactForm.phone.$error.required"> Phone Number is required.</span>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="addContactForm.$invalid" ng-click="PassDataToDisplyThroughUrl()">Submit</button> <br>
      </div>

    </form>
```

and here you go for my controller:

```
app.controller('addCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http',
function($scope, $location, $http) {
    $scope.formModel = {};
    $scope.PassDataToDisplyThroughUrl = function() {
        var url = 'display/' + $scope.formModel.userid + '/' + $scope.formModel.name
         + '/' + $scope.formModel.email + '/' + $scope.formModel.phone;
        $location.path(url);
        $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/', $scope.formModel)
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.successCallBack = 'You have successfully saved your contact';
        }, function(response){
            $scope.errorCallBack = 'Opps! Unable to save your data, please check your network';
        });
        $scope.formModel = {};
        $scope.addContactForm.$setPristine(); 
    }; 
}]);
```

It working fine, to remove validation error after submission clearing, i added this `$scope.addContactForm.$setPristine();` and it works but the only problem is, after submission, the form covered with a red border which i wasn't implemented, how can i remove this error?

If you dont get my words, you can run this code on your machine, and try to file up the form and submit, you will see this error.

if you got my words, can you please tell me where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to call function in form and pass event as a parameter.

2) make button type="submit".

3) Inside a function, after all your code execution you need to add 
event.form.reset();